# Ignore NewLIne inside a field in FileHelpers C#

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I am fairly new using FileHelpers Class for parsing the CSV. I have a file like this...

```
    "background","Info","Agent abcdefg
    ===================
    Context Tenant: {Vendor: 1, Customer: 719046046}","2,140.69","","7/11/2017 3:30 AM"
```

I would like to ignore any newline and would like to read that as one string. Can you please help?

so at the end of the line it is \r\n and i want this to be removed.

Comment: File.ReadAllText?

Comment: I am sorry Derek, that didn't work, or may be i am not sure how to implement. Can you provide some code please

Comment: The FileHelpers library should support new lines, in fields, if the fields are properly quoted (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511192/handling-newline-in-delimitedrecord-with-filehelpers)). It looks like your input fulfills this requirement. What exactly does not work? Additionally, maybe do you just need a `<fieldvalue>.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")` on the field value you read?

Comment: i tried using the Replace method as suggested, however it still appends the empty values to the each property in the object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [[FieldQuoted]](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FieldQuotedAttribute__ctor_6.htm) like this:

```
public class YourRecordClass
{
  [FieldQuoted()]
  public string Field1;

  [FieldQuoted()]
  public string Field2;

  [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultiLineMode.AllowForBoth)]
  public string Field3;

  [FieldQuoted()]
  public string Field4;

  [FieldQuoted()]
  public string Field5;

  [FieldQuoted()]
  public string Field6;
}
```

Comment: [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultiLineMode.AllowForBoth)] this does not change anything for newline as far as my example has shown. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`[FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultiLineMode.AllowForBoth)]` and `[FieldQuoted()]` didn't work for my case.

What I end up doing is reading the file using `File.ReadAllText`, replacing `\r\n` with an empty value and then feeding the read string to ``` FileHelperEngine``ReadString ```.

In my case the csv was generated with `\n` line endings and human comments were added using `\r\n`

```
  var engine = new FileHelperEngine<LLU>();

  var fileText = File.ReadAllText("myfile.csv");
  fileText = Regex.Replace(fileText, @"\r\n", ""); // Remove lines added by humans in comments

  var result = engine.ReadString(fileText)
```

Comment: It also didnot work for me. I want to keep the new line for reasons. thanks